# Do you have an open source example for saving data in RFID smart card reader

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, rfid

I am starting an open source project by using RFID card readers for saving data from an hotel information system. heres my scenario, i will be using rfid to save the data from the database and store it into the rfid cards. and then they can use the card as an id to their room.
btw my platform is wpf vb2010

Answer (score 0):

Not really an open source area, as it depends on the RFID system

Each one has it's own API/SDK and PHY (USB, RS232 etc)

Most manufacturers provide their own SDK usually free of charge

Comment: thanks TFD, but the SDK they provided doesn't provide sample code on writing and reading data into the smartcard, and the just provided the specs, that their machine can do. they provided one sample, but it didnt come with a sample code with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will depends which reader and which card technology you are using.
But you could be interested about our recently released [open source RFID library](http://liblogicalaccess.islog.com/) which supports different standard an proprietary hardware. Could be addressed in DotNet (C#, VB.NET ...) using the COM wrapper.